# PHP mail function HTML code showing

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send a mail using "mail" PHP function but it is not working as I expected because it's showing the HTML tags, and also it's adding the name of the server on the mail...!

PHP code:

```
$para = $mail;
$titulo = 'MyTitle';
$mensaje = '<html><body>';
$mensaje .= 'blablabla.';
$mensaje .= '</body></html>';
$cabeceras = 'From: mydomain.es <suscripcion@web.es>' . "\r\n".'Reply-To: mydomain@web.es' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

And that's the mail result (it's going to SPAM and also it shows the HTML code):

```
<html><body>blablablabla.</body></html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is normal. If an email is flagged as spam, the html on the email is usually not rendered.

Comment: Please check your spam score first , and post the result for our reference

http://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: Use PHPMailer and look on google for tips on how to avoid your mails being listed as spam. An example could be, emails being flagged as spam due to not having an unsubscribe link.

Comment: I'm going to check the PHPMailer, I hope this can solve this problem because I'm a little bit desperate with mails at the moment...!

Answer (score 0):

You should use it for headers part.

```
$cabeceras .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

$cabeceras .= "From: $from \r\n" .  
   "Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
   "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Comment: I tried with your headers but it's working the same way, I can see the HTML code and the e-mail "from" is showing the name of my hosting provider. I will have to ask them?

Comment: I tried again, but I can see the HTML. Also, the "From" is now "Apache" instead of the real one...! What can I do? Thanks in advance.